# Stopping XSLT including xmlns attribute when adding elements to XML file

Tags: xslt, web-config, elmah

Background: I am trying to script the configuration of Elmah so that, in production, I can run a script that will copy binaries and edit web.config file accordingly.

I decided to use XSLT to make the alterations to the web.config file.  To start with I want to add a `sectionGroup` in the `configSections` element like so.

```
  <sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    ....
  </sectionGroup>
```

Here is my XSLT template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:con="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add sectionGroup to configuration/configSections-->
  <xsl:template match="con:configSections[not (con:sectionGroup/@name='elmah')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <xsl:comment>ELMAH</xsl:comment>
      <sectionGroup name="elmah" >
        <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      </sectionGroup>
      <xsl:comment>/ELMAH</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it almost does what I want.  It generates the following `sectionGroup` XML.

```
  <!--ELMAH-->
  <sectionGroup name="elmah" xmlns="" xmlns:con="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
    ....
  </sectionGroup>
  <!--/ELMAH-->
```

Note the `xmlns` attribute.  The presence of this attribute really upsets ASP.Net (even though it is perfectly valid XML - albeit superfluous) and all requests result in a HTTP 500 error (see the section below for the error message).  The only error message that I could get out of

Removing the xmlns attribute fixes this problem.

I could use `xsl:element` to generate the new XML but this leads to very verbose and hard to read XSL.

So my question is how to tell XSLT **not** to add the xmls attribute in the resulting XML?

Thanks in advance.

---

**The error messages**

For information here are the error messages that ASP/IIS gives us: -

- When the root element of the config file (or any other element for that matter) has the prefix definition `xmlns:con="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"`, I get the following in a YSOD

  Configuration Error

  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

  Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns:con'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
- When any other element has 'xmlns' attribute attribute, I get the following message in a YSOD.

  Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'xmlns'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
- In other situations (I have not yet worked out when) I son't get a YSOD but just a default 500 page from IIS.  Despite enabling failed request tracing, I get no logs.  This is probably PEBKAC though.

---

**The solution to my problem**

Thanks to LarsH, Vincent Biragnet and Michael Kay for their responses, which between them have sorted out my problem.

Firstly - my XSLT as posted is wrong, as Michael and Vincent point out, the sectionGroup element *should* be in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0".

To sort this, I defined the default namespace in my XSLT like so `xmlns="http://schemas..."`.

But (why I do not know) the sectionGroup element is then  output as

```
<sectionGroup name="elmah" xmlns:con="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

(Isn't the xmlns:con superfluous?).  Anyway, the configuration parser barfs at the presence of xmlns:con.

But LarsH to the rescue - his suggestion suggestion of using `exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl con"` gets rid of those pesky things.

So the top of my (now working) XSLT now looks like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
    xmlns:con="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl con"
>
```

Thanks again for everyone's help

Comment: Have you tried adding a default xmlns to your xsl:stylesheet? Try adding `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"`.

Comment: +1 for good explanation of the solution.

Comment: Strange that `<sectionGroup>` is supposed to be in .NetConfiguration namespace; that would mean the config XML shown here is invalid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx

Comment: Yes - it appears that the config parser is happy to parse the file with or without it defining the default namespace to be "http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0".  I have just realized that this is not good for me - the XSLT that I have just written only works if the elements are in the MSConfig namespace.  I shall have to work on it so that it works with or without the default namespace declaration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if ASP.NET is upset merely by the presence of the `xmlns=""` pseudoattribute (as opposed to being upset because your content is in the wrong namespace), then that is a bug in ASP.NET and ought to be fixed. If your ELMAH content actually is in the wrong namespace, then of course that issue should be fixed (but [AFAICT, ELMAH config content should be in no namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx), so yours is fine).

It may help to add the exclude-result-prefixes attribute to your `<xsl:stylesheet>` start tag:

```
exclude-result-prefixes="con"
```

That should at least remove the `xmlns:con="..."` declaration from your output. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#literal-result-element) for more info.

However, since you are embedding the ELMAH XML (which is in no namespace) under some .NetConfiguration XML, which is in a namespace; if XSLT has decided to use the default namespace for the latter, then it has no choice but to use some sort of namespace declaration on the `<sectionGroup>` element... otherwise the the `<sectionGroup>` element will be in the .NetConfiguration namespace.

You haven't shown us the `<con:configSections>` part of your output XML... that would be helpful in diagnosing the cause, and finding a solution. In particular, does your output XML have `<con:configSections>` (i.e. using the `con` prefix) or `<configSections>` (using the default namespace)?

Comment: P.S. it would probably also help to see any error messages that ASP.NET is giving. If the 500 error page doesn't give any details, please turn on debug logging and check the log files.

Comment: "First, if ASP.NET is upset merely by the presence of the xmlns="" pseudoattribute ... then that is a bug in ASP.NET and ought to be fixed"   - I couldn't agree more.  A colleague of mine has run into the same issue whilst working on something different.

Answer (score 1):

In your template concerning the `con:configSections` element, you add a `sectionGroup` element that is not qualified, no namespace is linked with it.

Try to replace the sectionGroup part with that :

```
  <con:sectionGroup name="elmah" >
    <con:section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <con:section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <con:section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <con:section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  </con:sectionGroup>
```

If assume that `sectionGroup` has to be in the same namespace than `configSection`.

Another alternative is to keep your code without prefix and to add the following namespace declaration in the `sectionGroup` tag : `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"`

Comment: I don't think you can assume that sectionGroup is supposed to be in the same namespace as configSection. On the contrary, looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx, it appears that `<sectionGroup>` should be in no namespace. But I have no experience with ELMAH so someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the XSLT data model, namespace declarations and undeclarations are not attribute nodes. Don't think about namespace declarations and undeclarations: instead think about the names of your elements. You want an element whose name (using the notation (uri, local)) is

("http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0", "sectionGroup")

but you have asked for an element whose name is

("", "sectionGroup")

and this is what the processor has created for you. When this is serialized, this results in the namespace undeclaration xmlns="" being output in order to ensure that the element is in no namespace.

The fix is to create your element in the right namespace, which you can do, for example, by putting a namespace declaration on the literal result element.

Comment: Michael, are you sure he wants a sectionGroup element in the .NetConfiguration namespace? Looking at the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx it looks like it should be in no namespace.

Comment: Michael Kay is correct (are you the same Mr Kay who wrote the XSLT reference that is sat on my desk?) - the sectionGroup element should be in the MS config namespace.  That is an error in my original XSLT.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ChrisF: yes, the same Mr Kay. :-)

Answer (score -1):

> The namespace declaration has the following syntax. ***xmlns:prefix="URI"***.

```
<root>

<h:table xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

</root>
```

source : [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)